# Black output when using "Proximity (raster distance)" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, distance, proximity

I am using the "Proximity (raster distance)" tool in QGIS to calculate the distance from each pixel to the nearby forest.

I created the proximity map using the forest raster as input but the output seems all black and the values shown are zeros. I tried to change the symbology and see but its still the same.

Input data: Corine Landcover 2018 with classes 23, 24 and 25 (forest) only and clipped to the extent of Norway. Reprojected in QGIS to ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N - EPSG:25833.

Comment: Could you please add some additional information to this question. Is your input data projected? If so, what projection are you using? It could be that you are using a geographic Projection, so the output is in degrees and not metres / feet.

Comment: Yes, it is projected. Actually, the input data is of CLC 2018. I clipped the CLC layer to the extent of Norway and removed all other classes except the forest layers and saved it and reprojected it in QGIS in ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N - EPSG:25833.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I downloaded the CLC 2018 raster data to test how the Proximity Tool works with this data.

I was able to produce the following output:[image]

To do this I:

1. Kept the CLC data in its own projection
2. Using the Proximity Tool, I set the "List of Pixel Values" to 24 (which from what I could tell is a forest class)
3. Ran the Tool

The result did come up as appearing to be all black (as you experienced) but this seemes to be how the raster is presented, with no streching of the pixel values. QGIS is trying to draw the full range of pixel values (0 to 21900 in my case), so everything appears to be black.

This can be fixed one of two ways:

1. Right-click the result and select "Stretch using current extent", this should normalise the view and you should see pixels representing distance; or
2. Open the results properties, and open the "Symbology" menu. Choose the render type as Singleband Pseudocolor and play around with the settings. Here is mine:
   [image]

Hit apply and it should present as you wanted it.
Just remember the resolution of the image is 100m, so try stick to those intervals.
If you want to include more of the classes you can either add them in the Promiximity tool's options or you can Reclass the image identifying those pixel values representing Forest.

**UPDATE WITH SOURCE DATA**

Here is the data as provided through the WeTransfer link:
[image]

The legend shows the forest having a pixel value of 23.

Running the proximity tool I set the "List of pixel values" to 23.

[image]

The OUTPUT:

[image]

I opened the Layer Properties, and the Symbology Tab.
Changed the Render Type to "**Singleband pseudocolor**"
Changed the Mode to "**Quantile**"
Changed the "**Classes**" to 15
Hit the "**Classify**" button and then
**Apply**

Here is the result:

[image]

I think you may be there with your method, just a little refinement in the presentation.

Comment: I did as per your instructions above and still the values are zeros.

Comment: Can I send you my raster layer that I am trying to create proximity map from?

Comment: Sure thing. Let me know your choice of file transfer.

Comment: I can send it through wetransfer. The link is here: https://we.tl/t-1oXxmEMlT1.

Comment: Downloaded and it worked...will update the answer with your data

Comment: I did as per your instructions and I got the proximity map and the distance values by extracting in R. But there appears values (for example, 30 meters) where the occurrence points appears in the forest in the map.                                                                                   Also I did not understand about setting the target pixel values to 23. The forest raster has three classes: 23, 24 and 25.

Comment: To add the pixel values for forest, add "23,24,25" instead of just 23. These are the pixel values that the distances are calculated from. Try that and see if you are still getting funny values.

Comment: By adding the pixels 23,24, 25 in the target pixel values, the distance I got is 0 for the coordinates that are in the forest and 533 (pixel size) for few points.

Comment: Could you please edit your question with screen shots of what you have done and your results? I’m struggling for follow what you getting, when I got a result that looks right.

Comment: I created a new forest map in QGIS by only keeping the forest classes using raster calculator and made a proximity map and tried to extract points on that map. The results was same as before which displayed the distance in pixel values and I came to know that the distance from proximity map obtained from a raster is measured in pixels i.e. how far a point is from a pixel.

Comment: @BandanaAdhikari you have two choices. 1) Multiply the raster by 533 (pixel width) to get the distance in metres or 2) Change the output distance units to Georefrenced and not Pixel (default). Seems you are getting a result now. Glad to hear it.

Comment: Okay. I will do that accordingly. Thank you for your effort and time.